# how to find the best three routes using A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

In A* usually the result that you get is only one path. Is it possible though for a given origin and destination to have 3 recommended path according to A*? So the second returned is the second best path, and the third is the third best path..

I was thinking of maybe modifying the heuristic somehow to reflect this second and third best path.. What do you guys think?

**UPDATE:**
My implementation is in PHP and I am using a closed set. So if there's a way to do this, let me know.

Comment: In case you didn't know what A* was, as I didn't, it's a refinement of Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm.  See [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star_search_algorithm)

Comment: I did know what it is =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite easily if your language has support for backtracking/generators/iterators/coroutines.

```
# Python code
def astar(start):
    q = [start]    # priority queue
    while len(q) > 0:
        node = heappop(q)
        if isGoal(node):
            yield node
        for x in successors(node):
            heappush(q, x)
```

The `yield` keyword is similar to `return`, except that the function may be re-entered after a `yield` to get the next solution. To get the best three:

```
solutions = []
i = 0
for sol in astar(start):
    solutions.append(sol)
    if i == 3:
        break
    i += 1
```

**However**, this will not work if you use a *closed set* (i.e., [Russell & Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)'s *graph search* algorithm), since then part of the non-optimal solutions may be "cut off" when searching for the optimal one.

Comment: is there such way to do this in php?

Comment: is there any approach if I already have an implementation using closed set?

Comment: @EquinoX: I tend to stay away from PHP, but this trick can be performed in any language by building up a list of solutions inside the algorithm and returning that. I think you may be able to integrate the closed set in the node representation, but I don't immediately see how to do this correctly.

Comment: but again, if you use this approach maybe the second best route is almost similar with the first best route.. imagining it in a road.. maybe the only difference is that one takes a left turn near the end and the other takes a right turn.. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @EquinoX, to clarify: you would start out with empty list/array of solutions, then do an `append` (or whatever PHP calls it) instead of a `return` until the list is long enough for your purpose. This is called k-best search.