# Finding all paths though a graph. Is it possible (how?) to create an iterator of results, and would it be more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, iterator

Lets say I have a graph and a starting node. Each note has a weight.

The problem is to find all paths from the starting node where the sum of weights of the nodes are, say, five.

A simple approach is to do a depth first search, and, on discovering the sum of the current path is five, you could simply copy the solution into a list of solutions.

This simply solution would require you to search the entire tree until there are no more possibilities. What if you only needed one solution? Or two? Or the best out of 100? Wouldn't this approach waste potentially a large amount of memory storing all solutions?

I imagine you could write some sort of Iterator, where .next() simply continues the search until it finds a new path. This way you waste no storage or computation time.

I figured I'd ask if such a known pattern, or solution, or algorithm exists before trying to reinvent the wheel.

*Additionally*:

My actual problem is a special Iterator which finds all trees matching a certain condition, but I assumed the answer to the more general path problem would lead me closer to the solution to my problem. Any information on this would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think this could be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204444/how-to-find-the-best-three-routes-using-a-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass around a count in your function and return when you've reached that count.

```
void dfs(List<...> solutions, int count, ...)
{
  // check for solution and add to solutions

  if (solutions.size() == count)
    return;

  ...
  dfs(solutions, count, ...);
  if (solutions.size() == count)
    return;
  ...
}
```

This is probably the solution requiring the least changes (C# has functionality that allows you to have "some sort of Iterator, where .next() simply continues the search until it finds a new path", but Java doesn't, to my knowledge).

Alternate solutions are:

- Have multiple threads. Let one thread run your function, adding items to a global list. Let another thread access this list and presumably add some functionality to have the one running your function stop after adding an element to the list, and let the other thread resume it, or something like that.
- If you're using a recursive function, convert this to an iterative one, and store the `Stack` in a class variable after generating a single solution, and return, allowing you to continue again.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an algorithm used to solve exactly your problem.
It is called the Djikstra's Algorithm and is used to solve shortest path node problems.

You can find codes of it on the web, and probably learn more as well.
[Wikilink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)